# How to convert the values in cv::Mat to *CvMat

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, computer-vision

Its difficult to understood the concept of convert cv::Mat to *CvMat.can u tell me how to convert that with some example.i use opencv2.1 with vs in win 7.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Arangarajan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mat::operator CvMat()
```

cf. opencv 2.1 documentation